# Filtering a list by comparing enums against a user choice

Tags: c#, enum

I have a list of objects where one of the properties on the object class is an enum.

The program below simply loops through each item in the list, checks an int value, then checks the enum value for that item, then adds the item to another list when the condition is met.

I am using if-else statements, I attempted to use a switch statement but it doesn't seem possible to place 2 constants on a single case.

I'd like to know if there's a better / more elegant way to do this or is what I've done sufficient in this scenario?

**Program Code**

```
// User inputs number from 1 - 5        
int SelectedOppType = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

foreach (Opportunities Opp in OpportunitiesList)
{
    if (SelectedOppType == 1 && Opp.OpportunityStatusID == OpportunityStatus.Active) // Opp.OpportunityStatusID == OpportunityStatus.Draft
    {
        FilterdOppsList.Add(Opp);
    }
    else if (SelectedOppType == 2 && Opp.OpportunityStatusID == OpportunityStatus.Draft)
    {
        FilterdOppsList.Add(Opp);
    }
    else if (SelectedOppType == 3 && Opp.OpportunityStatusID == OpportunityStatus.Closed)
    {
        FilterdOppsList.Add(Opp);
    }
    else if (SelectedOppType == 4 && (Opp.OpportunityStatusID == OpportunityStatus.Active || Opp.OpportunityStatusID == OpportunityStatus.Draft))
    {
        FilterdOppsList.Add(Opp);
    }
    else if (SelectedOppType == 5)
    {
        FilterdOppsList.Add(Opp);
    }

}

foreach (var OppItem in FilterdOppsList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(OppItem.OppText);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Shortening `if`s

You add everything to the same list so you can concatenate all conditions and use only one `if` with a helper variable:

```
foreach (Opportunities Opp in OpportunitiesList)
{
    var canAdd =
        (SelectedOppType == 1 && Opp.OpportunityStatusID == OpportunityStatus.Active) ||
        (SelectedOppType == 2 && Opp.OpportunityStatusID == OpportunityStatus.Draft) ||
        (SelectedOppType == 3 && Opp.OpportunityStatusID == OpportunityStatus.Closed) ||
        (SelectedOppType == 4 && (Opp.OpportunityStatusID == OpportunityStatus.Active || Opp.OpportunityStatusID == OpportunityStatus.Draft)) ||
        (SelectedOppType == 5);

    if (canAdd)
    {
        FilterdOppsList.Add(Opp);
    }
}
```

---

## Other improvements

### Magic numbers

You should create an enum for the `SelectedOppType` and cast the `int` given by the user to it.

Example:

```
enum OppType
{
    OppType1 = 1,
    OppType2 = 2,
    OppType3 = 3,
    OppType4 = 4,
    OppType5 = 5,
}

var selectedOppType = (OppType)Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

I know the names `OppTypeX` are ugly but I don't know what the numbers mean, this is why we dislike them. They have no meaning.

Next, the logic can be extracted as an easier to maintain dictionary. Now that all values are enums we can easily build such a dictionary that I find by far is better then a `switch` nested in a loop. Besides, you can reuse the dictionary to display the options in other places (if you make it a filed or a property of some class).

```
var allowedOppTypeStatuses = new Dictionary<OppType, IEnumerable<OpportunityStatus>>
{
    [OppType.OppType1] = new[] { OpportunityStatus.Active },
    [OppType.OppType2] = new[] { OpportunityStatus.Draft },
    [OppType.OppType3] = new[] { OpportunityStatus.Closed },
    [OppType.OppType4] = new[] { OpportunityStatus.Active, OpportunityStatus.Draft },
    [OppType.OppType5] = Enumerable.Empty<OpportunityStatus>(),
};

foreach (Opportunities opp in OpportunitiesList)
{
    var canAdd = 
        allowedOppTypeStatuses[selectedOppType].Any(x => x == opp.OpportunityStatusID) || 
        !allowedOppTypeStatuses[selectedOppType].Any();

    if (canAdd)
    {
        FilterdOppsList.Add(opp);
    }
}
```

### Minor issues

- We use camelCase for local variables so `SelectedOppType` should be `selectedOppType`
- `Opportunities` - this doesn't look like a good name for a type, there seems to be more wrong with your code (unless it's an enum with `Flags` attribute).

Comment: Thanks for your help and other points of improvement. The last point about the type name, I was basing this on the class representing a real world object which could potentially point to a db, although it never will as this was just me learning.

Comment: this is great, thank you, I don't quite fully understand it yet and will have to analyze it further. I am also in the process of placing my original problem into a real world project which I need to wrap my head around because it'll be implemented different to how it was using a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

When `SelectedOppType == 5`, all values in `OpportunitiesList` will be added to `FilterdOppsList`, but only after evaluating many conditions unnecessarily. It would be better to handle this as a special case,
and add all values of `OpportunitiesList` in `FilterdOppsList` before ever entering the `foreach` loop.

Next, in the `foreach` loop, since `selectedOppType` doesn't change throughout the loop, regardless of the value of `opp`, it would make more sense to use conditionals on the value of `opp.OpportunityStatusID` instead of `selectedOppType`. You can rearrange the conditions to `switch` statement.

Putting it all together:

```
if(selectedOppType == 5)
{
    FilterdOppsList.AddRange(OpportunitiesList);
}
else
{
    foreach (Opportunities opp in OpportunitiesList)
    {
        bool shouldAdd = false;
        switch (opp.OpportunityStatusID)
        {
            case OpportunityStatus.Active:
                 shouldAdd = selectedOppType == 1 || selectedOppType == 4;
                 break;
            case OpportunityStatus.Draft:
                 shouldAdd = selectedOppType == 2 || selectedOppType == 4;
                 break;
            case OpportunityStatus.Closed:
                 shouldAdd = selectedOppType == 3;
                 break;
        }
        if (shouldAdd)
        {
            FilterdOppsList.Add(opp);
        }
    }
}
```